# Select different audio stream in Azure Communication services

Tags: azure, webrtc, azure-communication-services

I am researching a scenario where I setup a videoconference call app (like https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-web-calling-hero) with Azure Communication Services (ACS) and substitute the incoming audio stream with a different incoming audio stream (for example a translated English stream). In Azure Media Services this is possible, but this is lacking the videoconference functionality.

I cannot find any documentation on how to handle multiple audio streams for a single incoming video signal. Is this already possible in the current preview? Or should I switch to AWS Chime or Jitsi?

Comment: Just out of interest why have you tagged this question with "webrtc"? Is there some documentation with the Azure Communication Service that talks about webrtc support?

Comment: Please share your code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: My code is largely unchanged from the calling hero sample, so there is not much to share here.

I am struggling to find the correct path towards my solution:
- Anyone should be able to stream
- Anyone listing should see your stream, but be able to choose the right audio layer/stream

Not there yet. If I find an answer I will post it here.

Comment: Hi! Can you please open the issue on the GitHub? Someone will reply to you https://github.com/Azure/Communication/issues

Answer (score 0):

This is possible now with Raw Media Access APIs available. A sample code can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-web-calling-tutorial/tree/azure_communication_services_cognitive_services_speech_to_speech_translation) where we do exactly that.

The APis are a bit different from that sample, but you can see the updated versions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/get-started-raw-media-access?pivots=platform-web).